# Using gulp, browserify and react with addons

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to learn about gulp, browserify and react and have been knocking up a little test project.  This was fine until I decided to implement some animations in there.  Specifically this:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
```

I'm getting an error because "React.addons" is null.

I also have the issue that my build is taking an age - between 20 secs and a minute.  I think the reason is partly because react itself is being included in my bundle, whereas I would ideally like to retrieve it from a CDN (or at least keep it separate).

This is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return browserify('./public/js/app.js', {
        debug: false, bundleExternal: true
    })
    .transform(babelify, {"presets": ["es2015", "react"]})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'));
});
```

If I set "bundleExternal" to false then it does stop react being included in my js - but then nothing works because "react" is not found.  I found something about browserify-shims but couldn't get it to work from gulp.  And wasn't sure if it was the right way to go?

Apologies for the newbie question!

Answer (score 0):

To include ReactCSSTransitionGroup you need to install it first:

```
npm install react-addons-css-transition-group
```

Then just require it:

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');
```

Comment: That does fix one of the problems, thanks.  But my gulp build is still taking about a minute and the final JS file contains all of react.  Can I exclude the react parts from the build process?